# XPages - Lotus Notes

Tags: xpages, typeahead

There is too much space between the choices of the input text type ahead control. How to control it?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: Hi, I can understand what you mean to say. But it's not working. It's a simple text field with type ahead enabled. When type ahead returns some list of values say val 1,val 2,...val n. then there is space appearing at top & bottom of options. Where as if I change the same field to drop down then it's working fine.

Comment: Sounds like your lookup is returning a blank row. Check your data

Comment: No. It's the space between all options. No blank data.

Comment: Using Firebug or something like that, check the styling for the relevant element in CSS. Create a stylesheet to change the relevant setting.

Answer (score 4):

You want to reduce the distance between the entries in the type ahead choices list

[image]

Just add the following css to your XPages:

```
.tundra .dijitMenuItem {
    padding: 0px 2px;
}
```

The vertical padding between the type ahead choices is then 0px instead of 5px and the horizontal padding is 2px instead of 5px.

The list looks then like this:

[image]

Comment: You are correct. I tried this but it's impacting combobox type ahead options as well.So it's correcting the issue for text box type-ahead but creating new issue for combobox. :) I don't have enough credit to paste screen shot or else I can give u a better idea. Still you can see http://blog.hughesconnect.com/?p=160 where the dropdown box looks cool.But my challenge is to reduce the height of the options & it should not impact combobox.

Comment: You can set style class (for example shrinkOptions) to some container where your field is. Then CSS selector would be .shrinkOptions .tundra .dijitMenuItem. Other autocomplete controls outside this block will not be affected.

Comment: ".shrinkOptions" doesn't work because dijitComboBoxMenuPopup div (that's where the popup for choices is defined) is "outside" of form elements. Both popups for inputText and comboBox defined very similar. The only difference is the fieldname which is part of "id". So, if your inputText fields are all contain "inputText" in their fieldname, then you can use this css: `.dijitComboBoxMenu li[id*='inputText'] {
    padding: 0px 2px;
}`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am going to try it today. Will share the outcome at the earliest.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for all your valuable comments. Unfortunately it didn't worked for me.